# In below JSON, I am able to set the key in the cookies by cookies.set("key").... But how to get values from cookies such as name, email and grade

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

key:

```
{
    "token": "asasdnmsdbmbfdmnbfmfb", 
    "userData": {"id": "2", "name": "carrot", "email": [{"abc@google.com"}], 
    "grade": ["a","b"]
}
```

How to get name and email and gradefrom cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is [{"abc@google.com"}]. It's not a JSON format. It must be ["abc@google.com"]

You can test this

```
{"token": "asasdnmsdbmbfdmnbfmfb", "userData": {"id": "2", "name": "carrot", "email": ["abc@google.com"], "grade": ["a","b"]}}
```

Comment: You access it by key.userData.name,key.userData.email,key.grade

Comment: getting it as undefined

Comment: give me your JSON after you get

Comment: key: {
    "token": "asasdnmsdbmbfdmnbfmfb", 
    "userData": {"id": "2", "name": "carrot", "email": [{"abc@google.com"}], 
    "grade": ["a","b"]
}  This is the JSON....... how to get name in cookies if it is set in cookies like   cookies.set("Key")......

Comment: first, you should change your key to : {"token": "asasdnmsdbmbfdmnbfmfb", "userData": {"id": "2", "name": "carrot", "email": ["abc@google.com"], "grade": ["a","b"]}}

Comment: your current key is wrong format, so you can not get it

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = {
  "token": "asasdnmsdbmbfdmnbfmfb", 
  "userData": {"id": "2", "name": "carrot", "email": ["abc@google.com"]}, 
  "grade": ["a","b"]
}

console.log(input.userData.name);
console.log(input.userData.email[0]);
console.log(input.grade);
```